# Copy-construct from reference

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, copy-constructor

Consider this code

```
class Foo {
private:
    Bar bar; //note: no reference

public:
   Foo(Bar& b) : bar(b) { }
};
```

Will Bar get copy-constructed?

Comment: @ildjarn: What other possibilities are there? (Other than simply failing to compile, of course.)

Comment: @Oli : None, I was temporarily confused. ;-]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the signatures of `Bar`'s public constructors, either explicitly or implicitly defined.

To start with, the C++ standard allows for implicit conversion of references as long as the only difference in the underlying type is that the destination type is at least as *cv-qualified* than the source type, using the partial ordering defined in this table (C++11, §3.9.3/4):

> *no cv-qualiﬁer* < `const`
>   *no cv-qualiﬁer* < `volatile`
>   *no cv-qualiﬁer* < `const volatile`
>   `const`          < `const volatile`
>   `volatile`    < `const volatile`

So, taking that into account as well as §12.8/2:

> A non-template constructor for class `X` is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments.

if Bar has a constructor with *any* of the following signatures:

```
Bar(Bar&);
Bar(Bar const&);
Bar(Bar volatile&);
Bar(Bar const volatile&);
```

then yes, `b` will be copy-constructed into `Foo::bar`.

---

**EDIT:** *This was incorrect, I was thinking of `operator=` and the details of qualifying as a move-assignment operator.*

<s>Note that it's possible to have an eligible constructor that is not a copy constructor:</s>

```
Bar(Bar);
```

This will work (read: compile), but it is not technically a copy constructor.

Comment: "This will work (read: compile)". Does it? I don't have a standard handy, but ... http://ideone.com/9GIJu

Comment: @Rob : You're correct, I was thinking of `operator=` not technically being a copy-assignment operator when taking its argument by value. I'll edit.

Comment: Thnk you. And if I have `Bar & bar` and `Foo(Bar & b) : bar(b) {}`. Am I wrong in the assumption that a constructor will still be called for `bar`, meaning a new object of type `Bar`?

Comment: @Evgeni : Yes, that's wrong. Given that `bar` is a reference in that scenario, no copies are performed, just aliasing.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm not very experienced with C++ and not quite comfortable with references. But thats actually the behavior I prefer and want to achieve: simply aliasing the reference.

Comment: @Evgeni : Beware that holding references in a class makes that class non-assignable. In practice, this is often untenable, and it's better to use something like `std::shared_ptr` to avoid data duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your member variable `bar` will be copy constructed, that's one of the benefits of using an initializer list as opposed to assigning the value in the body of the constructor.

If the `Bar` class does not have an accessible copy constructor and the compiler can't generate a default one, the code will fail to compile.

When you pass a reference to a copy constructor, you should generally make it a `const` reference.